# inserting and retrieving array data in SQLite3

Tags: arrays, sqlite

Consider the following

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  no integer primary key,
  name varchar(15) not null,
  value1 integer not null,
  value2 integer not null,
  value3 integer not null,
  salary decimal(13, 2) not null
);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(1,'Kid1',100,10,20);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(2,'Kid2',200,700,10);
```

This creates the following table.

```
No   Name   Value1  Value2  Value3
----------------------------------
1   Kid1     100      10     20    
2   Kid2     200     700     10
```

Suppose I have fields 'Value1', 'Value2', ...,'Value100' so that inserting values in the above mentioned way is not efficient. Is it possible to store 100 values in an array and insert the values into the database? In a similar way is it possible to retrieve using an array?

Answer (score 0):

You create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    no integer primary key,
    name varchar(15) not null,
    salary decimal(13, 2) not null
);

CREATE TABLE test_values (
    test_id integer REFERENCES test(no),
    value integer not null
);
```

For each array value, insert a row into `test_values`. To get the array, run `SELECT value FROM test_values WHERE test_id = ?`.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example for insertion and retrieval?

Comment: @user4661268 There's already the retrieval query in the question. Inserting elements is done with a simple `INSERT` query for each element.

Comment: Sorry to say that the insertion is stil not clear for me! How can I insert 100 values to value1, vaue2, ..value100 if I have stored the values in an array, say 'myValues' of dimension 100?